# Assigning unique colours to different value combinations Python

Tags: python

I have a pivot table array with factors and X and Y coordinates such as the one below, and I have a look up table with 64 colours that have RGB values. I am trying to assign a colour to each factor combination and I'm not too sure how to go about doing so. For example, I need all A(0) B(1) C(0) D(0) to be RGB value (1 0   103) so that I can then paint those colours onto an image at point XY.

```
A  B  C  D  Xpoint  Ypoint
0  1  0  0  20      20
0  1  1  0  30      30
0  1  0  0  40      40
1  0  1  0  50      50
1  0  1  0  60      60
```

So far I only have code to open both my LUT and pivot table file and code to see the length of the pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

## load in LUT of 64 colours ##
with open('LUT64.csv') as d:
    LUT64 = pd.read_table(d, sep=',')
    print LUT64 

## load in XY COordinates ##
with open('PivotTable_2017-07-13_001.txt') as e:
    PivotTable = pd.read_table(e, sep='\t')
    print PivotTable

## Bring in image ## 
IM = Image.open("mothTest.tif")
IM.show()

#bring in number of factors
numFactors = 16    

#assign colour vectors to each factor combo
numPTrows = len(PivotTable)
print numPTrows

#Apply colour dots to image at XY coordinates
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` for your colour values with the first four values of your table as key (cast into a tuple):

```
table = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 20, 20],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 30, 30],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 40, 40],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 50, 50],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 60, 60],
]

##generating some colors
colors = [ (i,i,i) for i in range(0,256, 5)]

##defining iterator over color table
c_it = iter(colors)

##the dictionary for the color values    
color_dict = dict()

##assigning one color for each unique (A,B,C,D) tuple:
for entry in table:
    key = tuple(entry[0:4])

    if key not in color_dict:
        color_dict[key] = next(c_it)

print(color_dict)
```

The output of this is:

```
{
   (1, 0, 1, 0): (10, 10, 10), 
   (0, 1, 1, 0): (5, 5, 5), 
   (0, 1, 0, 0): (0, 0, 0)
}
```

**EDIT**:

In correspondence the edit of the OP's question, here a rough sketch of how to manipulate your `Pillow Image` (untested):

```
##looping through table:
for entry in table:
   key = tuple(entry[0:4])
   coord = tuple(entry[4:6])
   color = color_dict[key]
   IM.putpixel(coord,color)
```

Comment: I already have 64 colours chosen (so that they don't look similar to one another) in a text file that's been imported into an array. Does that mean I would have to turn my LUT into a table as well (instead of generating them as you did above)? Also, I will be using these colours with the X and Y coordinates in the table above, so would it still be possible to associate the colours in the dict with the XY coordinates?

Comment: @mdicrist It is hard to be specific without seeing all your code, but basically the answers to your questions are yes and yes. If you have your colours in an array, you should be able to just replace my `colors` with that array. Then, when you iterate through your `table`, you first pick the coordinates and then create the keys they way that I did. That being said, there might be a much simpler solution to your problem, but for that you would have to show your code.

Comment: Thank you! I have posted my code. I didn't post it before as all I did was bring in my files as arrays and check the length of the pivot table (which is 4072 rows).

Comment: @mdicrist please see the edit to my answer. hopefully you can get it to work with some small adjustments...